# Import other fbx files, and the pivot always outside the objects with a parent relationship line

Tags: modeling

I imported a ready-made grass .fbx file that was made by others, but the pivot was always shown outside the object with a black dashed line, which seems like the parent relationship line.

My purpose was to make the position change of this grass object, but every time I opened the project again, the grass remained in the same location that hadn't changed.

[image]

Comment: Alt-P with the object selected in Object mode will unparent it, but it's not clear what it's currently parented to. It's possible that it's parented to an Empty with the empty hidden.

Comment: Thank you very much for refreshing, unfortunately, I have tried to unhide everything to see whether something was parented incorrectly,.Whilst there was not, the grass. fbx itself was an assembled file originally, so I was not able to unparent it by selecting the grass file. I'm also wondering how to share my project file in this platform as this is my first time using this platform……

Comment: As long as your Blend file is under 30Meg in size you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ofmt1ter1ff9t45dop2sa/problem-file.zip?rlkey=h9zcgzgjflgpvpqruv5ipnxcz&dl=0
I don't know whether this link can be shown, which is the link I upload my files onto DropBox cloud disk as the size of the blend file exceeded 30MB

Comment: It downloads and opens fine in Blender but I'm afraid something that complex is outside my experience. Maybe someone else here can help?

Comment: You're so responsive! , maybe I imported the camera things as well, I will figure out it little by little,really appreciate it